# What does this "after deadly shooting" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The showdown came after the fatal shooting of a campus police officer at the Massachusetts Institute of Technology.

So is the police officer dead or did he shoot someone else dead?

Comment: That cannot be “a police” who is dead, because *police* is always plural.

Answer (score 2):

This means that the officer was fatally shot.  If they meant to say that the officer fatally shot someone else, they might say "The showdown came after the fatal shooting by a campus police officer at the Massachusetts Institute of Technology."

Comment: But intrinsically, does "shooting of <somebody>" have ambiguity in English?

Comment: No, "shooting of" always refers to the person who was shot, at least in my experience.

Comment: This is more general. "*Object* was *verb*ed" => "The *verb*ing of *object*", when talking about a specific instance, and sometimes about multiple or continued happeningss, e.g. "The cattle was branded" => "After the branding of the cattle, it was released to graze.".  Technically, *verb*ing is a sort of a stand-in for an "actual" noun, and such noun is preferably used when available. "The girl was murdered" => "The murder of the girl", not "The murdering". This happens mostly with words where the verb and the noun are the same (like "murder"). The "of" still stands and resolves any ambiguity.